# pytest - How to know what markers are selected

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Is there any way in pytest to know what markers are selected from the command line?

I have some tests marked as "slow" that need a heavy treatment. I want to process the treatment only if the marker slow is activated.

```py
heavy_var = None

def setup_module(module):
    global heavy_var

    # Need help here!?
    if markers["slow"]:
        heavy_var = treatment()


def test_simple():
    pass


@pytest.mark.slow():
def test_slow():
    assert heavy_var.x == "..."
```

How can i know if the slow marker is selected or not? When i call pytest with `-m not slow` `markers["slow"]` will be False otherwise True.

Comment: Not really - not from a `setup_module`, it's for compatibility with `nose` and xUnit and is pretty limited; you can replace it with an equivalent fixture though. And not a markers list/dict - only the string you entered from the command line, e.g. you can access the `not slow` string.

Comment: So, the only way to do what i want is to use sys.argv?

Comment: `sys.argv` will also give you only the `-m` string arg, so you have to do the parsing yourself.

Comment: If it's not possible to do it with pytest (without parsing argv), is there an other clean way to process treatment only if some markers are activated?

Comment: Oh sure, this is possible - I was too concentrated on the question title. Let me give you an example shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to run some code only if tests marked with `slow` were selected, you can do that by filtering the test items in a module-scoped fixture that replaces the `setup_module`. Example:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module', autouse=True)
def init_heavy_var(request):
    for item in request.session.items:
        if item.get_closest_marker('slow') is not None:
            # found a test marked with the 'slow' marker, invoke heavy lifting
            heavy_var = treatment()
            break
```